# How to prevent Local File Download in this PHP code?

Tags: php, security

I have this php code :

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_GET['name']."\""); 
$file_content = file_get_contents($_GET['name']);
echo $file_content;

?>
```

In this case, the attacker can download files on my site with this request:

`localhost/file.php?name=../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

I need a way to prevent users from downloading anything except `.zip` file from the current directory.

Comment: if (strpos($_GET['name'], '..') !== false) exit;

Comment: @IgorPantović That is not sufficient, just start using absolute path names

Comment: @MichaelHelwig Oh my, indeed, terrible oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before opening the file, you should check that the content of `$_GET['name']` is legit.

In particular, in your case, check that:

- it ends with `.zip`
- it does not contain a NUL byte to prevent premature string termination (see [Null bytes related issues](http://php.net/security.filesystem.nullbytes))
- it doesn't contain a path separator (neither `/` nor `\`).

Here’s an example:

```
$filename = $_GET['name'];
if (strpos($filename, "\0") !== false) {
    // contains NUL byte
} else if (substr(strtolower($filename), -4) !== '.zip') {
    // doesn’t end with ".zip"
} else if (basename($filename) !== $filename) {
    // contains path separator
} else if (!is_file($filename)) {
    // file does not exist
} else {
    // everything is fine
}
```

Comment: That’s not enough. Just think of `/etc/passwd%00.zip` (ends with `.zip` but contains string terminating NUL byte) or `./../../etc/passwd` (does not start with `..`).

Comment: Indeed, I missed some cases. I adapted my answer accordingly. (However, I'm not mentionning the NUL byte trick, because I'm not sure I fully understands it)

Comment: It’s still not sufficient/accurate enough.

Comment: Then, please, submit an answer (or edit mine): I'll be glad to learn how it should be handled